# Is it possible to get a Bloomberg field name in Excel?

Tags: excel, bloomberg

[Question]

Is there a function in Bloomberg Excel plug-in that displays the name of a field?

[Background]

I am using Bloomberg Excel plug-in to regularly download data into a spreadsheet. I use a pull-down list to select different fields from a list, and the field name is passed to a separate sheet where a table is automatically populated with data from Bloomberg.

There are occasionally other users who access my spreadsheet and they may not have the knowledge to understand what exactly is being downloaded. It would be great if whenever they choose a particular field (for example IS_EPS) the name of the filed could be displayed (in this instance "Basic Earnings per Share").

Answer (score 6):

There is a spreadsheet function BFieldInfo that does this.

```
=BFieldInfo("IS_EPS","des")
```

will return "Basic Earnings per Share". Use "des,def" if you also want the full description:

[image]